# Parsing an RSS Feed in an Android Application

Tags: android, rss

I am trying to retrieve data from an RSS Feed. My program is working well, with one exception. 
The feed has items that are structured as:

```
<title></title>
<link></link>
<description></description>
```

I can retrieve the data, but when the title has a '&' character the string returned stops at the character before. So for example, this title:

```
<title>A&amp;T To Play Four Against Bears</title>
```

I am only getting back an 'A', when I expect to get back 'A&T To Play Four Against Bears'.

Can anyone tell me if I can modify my existing RSSReader class to account for the presence of an &amp:

```
import android.util.Log;
```

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.CharacterData;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class RSSReader {

```
private static RSSReader instance = null;

private RSSReader() {
}

public static RSSReader getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new RSSReader();
    }
    return instance;
}

public ArrayList<Story> getStories(String address) {
    ArrayList<Story> stories = new ArrayList<Story>();
    try {
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        URL u = new URL(address);
        Document doc = builder.parse(u.openStream());
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
            Story currentStory = new Story(getElementValue(element, "title"),
                    getElementValue(element, "description"),
                    getElementValue(element, "link"),
                    getElementValue(element, "pubDate"));
            stories.add(currentStory);
        }//for
    }//try
    catch (Exception ex) {
        if (ex instanceof java.net.ConnectException) {
        }
    }
    return stories;
}

private String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e) {
    try {
        Node child = e.getFirstChild();
        if (child instanceof CharacterData) {
            CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
            return cd.getData();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.i("myTag2", ex.toString());
    }
    return "";
} //private String getCharacterDataFromElement

protected float getFloat(String value) {
    if (value != null && !value.equals("")) {
        return Float.parseFloat(value);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

protected String getElementValue(Element parent, String label) {
    return getCharacterDataFromElement((Element) parent.getElementsByTagName(label).item(0));
}
```

}

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Can you give a link of rss feed?

Comment: sure: http://www.ncataggies.com/rss.dbml?db_oem_id=24500&RSS_SPORT_ID=74515&media=news

Comment: I'm thinking it may be the way the data is being extracted from the title tags

Comment: For my knowledge that rss feed has problems, they had to encode & character to &amp; in title. (<title>
<![CDATA[ North Carolina A&T Baseball Headline News ]]>
</title>(

Comment: Sorry, error is somewhere else. term CDATA is used about text data that should not be parsed by the XML parser. So I think "<title>A&amp;T To Play Four Against Bears</title>" had to be "<title>A&T To Play Four Against Bears</title>) or CDATA hadn't be used.

Comment: So I can't really do anything about it?

Answer (score 1):

I tested that rss feed with the parser I use and It parsed like below.
Seems it is parsable but As I wrote in comments, because of both CDATA is used and also escaped, there are texts like "A&T" but you can replace them after you parse xml.

```
D/*** TITLE      : A&T To Play Four Against Longwood
D/*** DESCRIPTION: A&amp;T baseball takes a break from conference play this weekend.
D/*** TITLE      : Wilkerson Named MEAC Rookie of the Week
D/*** DESCRIPTION: Wilkerson was 6-for-14 for the week of April 9-15.
D/*** TITLE      : Lights, Camera, Action
D/*** DESCRIPTION: A&amp;T baseball set to play nationally televised game on ESPNU.
D/*** TITLE      : Resilient Aggies Fall To USC Upstate
D/*** DESCRIPTION: Luke Tendler extends his hitting streak to 10 games.
D/*** TITLE      : NCCU Defeats A&T In Key Conference Matchup
D/*** DESCRIPTION: Kelvin Freeman leads the Aggies with three hits.
```

I am sharing most part of rss feed parser I used for you to compare what is different from yours.

**XmlPullFeedParser.java**

```
package com.nesim.test.rssparser;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;

import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Xml;

public class XmlPullFeedParser extends BaseFeedParser {

  public XmlPullFeedParser(String feedUrl) {
    super(feedUrl);
  }

  public List<Message> parse() {
    List<Message> messages = null;
    XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
    try {
      // auto-detect the encoding from the stream
      parser.setInput(this.getInputStream(), null);
      int eventType = parser.getEventType();
      Message currentMessage = null;
      boolean done = false;
      while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT && !done){
        String name = null;
        switch (eventType){
          case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
            messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
            break;
          case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
            name = parser.getName();
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(ITEM)){
              currentMessage = new Message();
            } else if (currentMessage != null){
              if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(LINK)){
                currentMessage.setLink(parser.nextText());
              } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(DESCRIPTION)){
                currentMessage.setDescription(parser.nextText());
              } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(PUB_DATE)){
                currentMessage.setDate(parser.nextText());
              } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(TITLE)){
                currentMessage.setTitle(parser.nextText());
              } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(DATES)){
                currentMessage.setDates(parser.nextText());
              } 
            }
            break;
          case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
            name = parser.getName();
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(ITEM) && currentMessage != null){
              messages.add(currentMessage);
            } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(CHANNEL)){
              done = true;
            }
            break;
        }
        eventType = parser.next();
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e("AndroidNews::PullFeedParser", e.getMessage(), e);
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return messages;
  }
}
```

**BaseFeedParser.java**

```
package com.nesim.test.rssparser;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public abstract class BaseFeedParser implements FeedParser {

  // names of the XML tags
  static final String CHANNEL = "channel";
  static final String PUB_DATE = "pubDate";
  static final  String DESCRIPTION = "description";
  static final  String LINK = "link";
  static final  String TITLE = "title";
  static final  String ITEM = "item";
  static final  String DATES = "dates";
  private final URL feedUrl;

  protected BaseFeedParser(String feedUrl){
    try {
      this.feedUrl = new URL(feedUrl);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  protected InputStream getInputStream() {
    try {
      return feedUrl.openConnection().getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

**FeedParser.java**

```
package com.nesim.test.rssparser;

import java.util.List;

public interface FeedParser {
  List<Message> parse();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you didn't change your code as I provided. If you insist to parse it like that, you need to get xml first and manipulate it for correct parsing.
I am also giving a class to get xml as text at the end of this message. 
Please change your code like this, try and write result.

If you change this lines you will succeed.

**Delete this lines from getStories function:**

```
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
URL u = new URL(address);
Document doc = builder.parse(u.openStream());
```

**Instead of those deleted lines, add these:**

```
WebRequest response = new WebRequest("http://www.ncataggies.com/rss.dbml?db_oem_id=24500&RSS_SPORT_ID=74515&media=news",PostType.GET);
String htmltext = response.Get();

int firtItemIndex = htmltext.indexOf("<item>");
String htmltextHeader = htmltext.substring(0,firtItemIndex);
String htmltextBody = htmltext.substring(firtItemIndex);

htmltextBody = htmltextBody.replace("<title>", "<title><![CDATA[ ");
htmltextBody = htmltextBody.replace("</title>", "]]></title>");

htmltextBody = htmltextBody.replace("<link>", "<link><![CDATA[ ");
htmltextBody = htmltextBody.replace("</link>", "]]></link>");

htmltextBody = htmltextBody.replace("<guid>", "<guid><![CDATA[ ");
htmltextBody = htmltextBody.replace("</guid>", "]]></guid>");
htmltextBody = htmltextBody.replace("&amp;", "&");
htmltext = htmltextHeader + htmltextBody;

Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(htmltext);
```

**WebRequest.java**

```
package com.nesim.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.CookieStore;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.ClientContext;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCookieStore;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;


public class WebRequest {
  public enum PostType{
    GET, POST;
  }

  public String _url;
  public String response = "";
  public PostType _postType;
  CookieStore _cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

  public WebRequest(String url) {
    _url = url;
    _postType = PostType.POST;
  }

  public WebRequest(String url, CookieStore cookieStore) {
    _url = url;
    _cookieStore = cookieStore;
    _postType = PostType.POST;
  }

  public WebRequest(String url, PostType postType) {
    _url = url;
    _postType = postType;
  }

  public String Get() {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    try {




      // Create local HTTP context
      HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

      // Bind custom cookie store to the local context
      localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, _cookieStore);

      HttpResponse httpresponse;
      if (_postType == PostType.POST)
      {
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(_url);
        httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost, localContext);
      }
      else
      {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(_url);
        httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httpget, localContext);
      }

      StringBuilder responseString = inputStreamToString(httpresponse.getEntity().getContent());

      response = responseString.toString();
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
      // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
      // shut down the connection manager to ensure
      // immediate deallocation of all system resources
      httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }

    return response;
  }

  private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

    // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,Charset.forName("iso-8859-9")));
    // Read response until the end
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
      total.append(line);
    }

    // Return full string
    return total;
  }
}
```

**Important:**

Don't forget to change package name at first line in WebRequest.java

*package com.nesim.test;*

**Results:**

**After these changes, you will get these:**

```
D/title:  Two Walk-Off Moments Lead To Two A&T Losses
D/description: The Lancers win in their last at-bat in both games of Saturday&#39;s doubleheader.
D/title:  A&T To Play Four Against Longwood
D/description: A&T baseball takes a break from conference play this weekend.
D/title:  Wilkerson Named MEAC Rookie of the Week
D/description: Wilkerson was 6-for-14 for the week of April 9-15.
D/title:  Lights, Camera, Action
D/description: A&T baseball set to play nationally televised game on ESPNU.
D/title:  Resilient Aggies Fall To USC Upstate
D/description: Luke Tendler extends his hitting streak to 10 games.
```

**Your parsing returns these:**

```
D/title  : Two Walk-Off Moments Lead To Two A
D/description: The Lancers win in their last at-bat in both games of Saturday&#39;s doubleheader.
D/title  : A
D/description: A&amp;T baseball takes a break from conference play thisweekend.
D/title  : Wilkerson Named MEAC Rookie of the Week
D/description: Wilkerson was 6-for-14 for the week of April 9-15.
D/title  : Lights, Camera, Action
D/description: A&amp;T baseball set to play nationally televised game on ESPNU.
D/title  : Resilient Aggies Fall To USC Upstate
D/description: Luke Tendler extends his hitting streak to 10 games.
```